# pytest_collection_modifyitems: evaluate final pytestmarks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am using [`pytest_collection_modifyitems`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) to change pytest items to be executed.

What is the proper way of evaluating final marks of given item? Note that marks can come from different places, like function itself, parametrize param or pytestmark module-level variable)

Currently I build list of marks manually, but I assume that there is a better API for that.

Current code:

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    for item in items:
        for mark in [*item.own_markers, *item.callspec.marks, *getattr(item.module, 'pytestmark', [])]:
            ...  # do something
```

Ideal final solution (`evaluate_marks` is mocked-up method I search for):

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    for item in items:
        for mark item.evaluate_marks():
            ...  # do something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `item.iter_markers(optional_marker_name)` iterator.